# What causes differences in limits of detection?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, mass-spectrometry

I'm wondering what causes the limits of detection (LOD) to vary between different compounds, when calculated from the data obtained from one sample.

I've analyzed a 0,1 µg/ml sample, containing fluorene, fluoranthene and benzo[*a*]pyrene in toluene, using GC-MS. I calculated the LODs to be 0,04 µg/ml, 0,02 µg/ml and 0,03 µg/ml. What could be the reason for the differences between the values?

Comment: Have you got any ideas?

Comment: None whatsoever. I'm not very familiar with MS and I could easily imagine it's got something to do with how MS works.

Comment: Different compounds (from one sample) result in separate signals and very likely different sensitivity from MS measurement. It's related to how easy the ionization is for each compound. In addition, experimental errors always exist. Are you trying to determine the concentrations of those compounds?